# PlayableAsset from AssetBundle is null on Oculus Quest 1

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, assetbundle

I'm making Oculus Quest 1 app in Unity.
First I describe whole workflow:

1. In unity_project_1 im making animation using Unity Timeline window.
2. After animation is done I'm building asset bundle with prefab containing components: Animator, PlayableDirector, Audio Source, everything that is needed to recreate animation.
3. Bundle is sent to the server.
4. In another project I'm downloading this bundle, extracting data and playing animation during runtime - everything works fine.
5. Same thing for android mobile phone, example scene works perfectly fine on the device.
6. Now I'm trying to do the same thing on Oculus Quest 1. Bundle is downloading correctly, but **for some reason PlayableAsset is null**.

I made it work once, when I found that project in which I'm building asset bundles was made in editor ver. 2021.3.16f1, but VR project was 2021.3.17f1. After downgrading VR project to editor version 2021.3.16f1 and rebuilding apk - animation worked. After that I left project for another day. Now today, after rebuilding (for some logs only) PlayableAsset is null again.

Now versions are correct, everything happening in RAM (downloading data, bundles, etc), so I think permissions are not the issue. I built asset bundle for Android with all dependencies... I have no clue what else I can do. Any tips?